# How to close the (local) Debug window/palette

Tags: front-end

I have this local debug window that is so annoying

[image]

How can I hide it? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: Yes, you can. As a general rule, when dealing with frontend questions don't forget to specify your version and platform

Comment: You can turn it on/off with the menu entry `Evaluation > Debugger`

Comment: @BrettChampion I wasn't paying attention and answered without realising that we're on meta.

Comment: @belisarius, my guess is W7, MMA 8.something :P

Comment: @Rojo [I don't like islands :)](http://www.lpl.arizona.edu/~bcohen/phantom_tollbooth/conclusions.html)

Comment: @belisarius does it again. lol

Comment: Easier to mistype than to misprintscreen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 1. You may turn off this menu selection:

[image]

(Or uncheck `Debugger` to turn off the entire apparatus.)

### 2. The tools are:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

#### Version 10 bugs

*Mathematica* 10 (and later) seems to have some strange problems regarding the debugger tools window.  In 10.0 and 10.1 under Windows once I turn on the debugger I experience the window persisting even after the menu is unchecked; it reappears when I close a Notebook window.  I suspect this has to do with the change to individual window menus rather than a menu bar.  Fortunately in my case restarting *Mathematica* removes the tools window, however other people have experienced it persisting between sessions; see:

- [Annoying window. How to remove it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56152/121)
- [Issue with the debug tools window](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76473/121)
- [How to close the debugger window](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83471/121)
- [Whye does the Debugger Control Palette keep popping up?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125262/121)

Comment: What about the second part " What is the purpose of it?":)

Comment: @Ajasja okay, updated; If *you* want to present a lecture on the use of a debugger be my guest. :^)

Comment: didn't work for me :( stoopid thing still there ... any other suggestions?

Comment: @Solarmew Are you using version 10?  I have experienced weird behavior with the debugger window in 10/10.1.  Once it is turned on in a session it seems to keep popping back up even when **Debugger** is unchecked.  However after I restart *Mathematica* it does not reappear.

Comment: I tried restarting it, but it came back XD ... But ctrl+shirt starting it worked :]

Answer (score 2):

In version 10, we need to Evaluation->Quit Kernel and then Start Kernel to prevent the debugger tool window from reappear.

Comment: Doesn't toggling Evaluation -> Debugger work?  It works for me in 10.0, 10.3 and 10.4.  What 10.x version do you have?

Comment: No, toggling Evaluation -> Debugger will not prevent the debugger tool window from reappear if you open a new nb file, my version is 10.4.1 and 10.3.1

Comment: Strange, it doesn't happen on my system.  Maybe it's time to reset the front end (hold Ctrl-Shift or Command-Shift during startup)?  I have the same two versions on OS X.