# Annoying window. How to remove it?

Tags: front-end, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.0 or later**

---

[image: How do I remove this wondow from my mathematica?]

How do I remove this window from my *Mathematica*?  Unchecking the **Debugger** menu item as described in [How to close the (local) Debug window/palette](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6807/121) does not work.

Comment: That's the debugging panel.  Turn it off by un-checking menu item **Evaluation** > **Debugger**.

Comment: I just reopened this question because after turning on and off that panel it kept reappearing during the session.  This may have something to do with the multiple-menu-bars in v10 under Windows, or it may not.  Since it is possible to have the debugging panel visible *and* have the **Debugger** *unchecked* this is not such an obvious thing after all.

Comment: Well sometimes it's better to have older versions... :)

Comment: I have added the `bugs` tag based on confirmation in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76525/121) to a duplicate question.  (By the way a Merge would move that answer here; if anyone has an opinion about doing that please voice it.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Do we have steps to reproduce this problem?  Do we know if it is Windows-specific?  I have never seen it on Mac.  BTW the Linux version also has one menu bar per Windows (and has had that before Windows).

Comment: I've had this happen pre-10 also, and in 10. IIRC, to get rid of it I had to quit/restart kernel.

Comment: @Szabolcs I guess so.  (1) Start *Mathematica* and open a New Notebook.  (2) Check **Debugger**, then uncheck *Debugger**.  (The palette appears and disappears as expected.) (3) Close the Notebook.  The Debugger palette reappears along with the **New Notebook** / **Open** / **Quit** dialog, but the **Debugger** item in the menu of that window is *not* checked.  If a **New Notebook** is opened the **Debugger** remains visible, and the menu item is still not checked.

Comment: They needs to debug the debugger tool.

Comment: it is now version 12.1 and having very similar issue but with me it is the Debugger toolbar that refuses to turn off only in one Notebook even though it is not set in Evaluation -> Debugger. Should I submit a bug report?