# Issue with the debug tools window

Tags: bugs, debugging, installation

I have an issue with the debug tools window.  It appears on its own periodically.  I have turned it off in the Evaluation menu, and have gone to "Debugger Controls" and deselected "Show Debugger Tools Window".  When I try to move it, it goes away, then comes back in a few minutes.  Rebooting does not help.  It happens on all notebooks. I am using Mathematica 10 for students.  Any suggestions, besides uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Related question (how it is *supposed* to work): [(6807)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6807/121)

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. I contacted mma support (I have a premier license) and they said that this is a bug. I reported this problem in version 10.0.0 and it still exists in 10.0.2.0, so who knows when it will be fixed.

Comment: This bug remains in the 11.0 version.