# How to close the debugger window

Tags: windows, debugging

So this thing just popped out of nowhere X.x ... I tried getting rid of it yesterday following suggestions in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6807/how-to-close-the-local-debug-window-palette) and I could've sworn it went away. But today I opened my laptop and the damn thing was back @.@ ... and now I don't know how to kill it again...

[image]

Comment: That sounds like the kind of weird behavior you get when something gets corrupted. This helped me with a similar problem. http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Comment: that did it, thanks! how weird tho X.x i wonder what broke in the first place...

Comment: If you are using 10.X.X I shall close this as a duplicate of: [(76473)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76473/121)

Comment: Mr. Wizard. I am. Go ahead :] Like 50% of the time I have a question I wish I could just msg you so i dun have to spam XD