# Whye does the Debugger Control Palette keep popping up?

Tags: debugging, palettes, user-interface

The Debugger Control Palette keeps popping up on my screen. It appeared for the first time when I checked the Debugger item in the Evaluation menu. Later on I unchecked the Debugger item and I expected the Debugger Control Palette to go away. It sort of does it but occasionally and randomly it pops up on my screen. If I click on it nothing happens, but if I try to drag it it disappears instantly. But later on, for no reason, it pops up again.

I am running Mathematica 11.0.0.0 on Windows 10 Professional.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this nuisance? I already tried quitting Mathematica and starting it again, to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: I sometimes meet this problem, but restart mathematica will always work.